# C# NET Core EF data fetch from database and check the data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

So im trying to contact the MySQL database to check if a player account exist and if so to fetch that data. But i have no idea how the MySQL functions works in NET Core (using pomelo mysql)

So far i have this:

```
public PlayerData Account
    {
        get
        {
            using (var db = new DataDbContext())
            {
                return db.Players.Include(x => x.PlayerName == this.PlayerName).SingleOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
```

But i have no idea how to make on this a check to see if the account exist or not, and if it does to fetch the data

PlayerData class
[PlayerData.cs](https://github.com/Banditul/Sampsharp-GameMode/blob/development/TruckingData/Data/PlayerData.cs)

DataDbContext class [DataDbContext.cs](https://github.com/Banditul/Sampsharp-GameMode/blob/development/TruckingData/Data/DataDbContext.cs)

(Added github links as i had troubles putting the code here)

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? If it returns the `default` object then it doesn't exist else it will return a `PlayerData` object with the populated data.

Comment: .Include doesn't do what you perhaps think it does. Try simply `db.Players.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PlayerName == this.PlayerName);` instead. This will be turned into a WHERE clause in the SQL. If it returns `null` or a default object then the record doesn't exist. If it returns the record, then it does. BTW your code is standard Entity Framework code, it's not specific to MySQL databases at all. Find an Entity Framework tutorial and it will get much easier.

Comment: `"Include(x => x.PlayerName == this.PlayerName)"` is not a mysql function, its entity framework. You could consider `return db.Players.Where(x => x.PlayerName == this.PlayerName).SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: Alright, thank you guys. This seems so strange as until now i only use SQL commands and stuff. This is new lol I will take a look at the tutorials about entity framework and i will solve this

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt your code a bit to make it works

```
var player = db.Players.First(x => x.PlayerName == this.PlayerName);

if (player is null) {
    // Player does not exist
}
```